# Unable to set the property of a struct

Tags: go, struct

I'm trying to learn how to use structs in go.

I have the following package

```
// src/db/db.go
package db

type DB struct {
  pk string
}

func (db DB) SetPk(s string)  {
  db.pk = s
}
func (db DB) GetPk() string {
  return db.pk
}
```

And this is my main.go

```
package main

import (
  "log"
  "db"
)

func main() {

  d := db.DB{}
  d.SetPk("Hello World")
  log.Println(d.GetPk())

}
```

When I run the command `go run main.go`, I get a line break in my command prompt.  I verified that both the SetPk and GetPk are being fired, and that the SetPk is assigning a value to db.pk.  But the moment GetPk is fired, db.pk is empty again.

How do I get the db object to retain the pk value and return it in GetPk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you need to make the methods work off of a pointer to the variable and not a copy. Currently each method only uses a copy of the original (which is blank) to run the method. Below will work.

```
// src/db/db.go
package db

type DB struct {
  pk string
}
// Use the pointer back to the object
func (db *DB) SetPk(s string)  {
  db.pk = s
}
// Use the pointer back to the object
func (db *DB) GetPk() string {
  return db.pk
}
```